# layers control and geojson on mapbox/leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm mixing up [the choropleth example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth/)

and [the layes control example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers-control/)

Using layers control with tiles, i've no problems, it works perfectly, but i need to work with geojson and this is my problem:
the gejson layer is ever in foreground and tiles on background.
but i need that when selecting a "streets" tile in layercontrol it come in foreground and l.geojson in backgrnd.
i need it to show labels. Using trasparency is not good for my purposes.
any solution?
here a part of the code:

```
  var mapdataviz = L.mapbox.map('map', 'andria.h41061in')
   .setView([39.0981, 16.5619], 8);
 mapdataviz.legendControl.addLegend(document.getElementById('legend-content').innerHTML);


  L.control.layers({
    'city': L.mapbox.tileLayer('andria.cal_com_ief1'),
    'com_geojson': L.geoJson(comData,  {
      style: getStyle,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(mapdataviz),
    'streets': L.mapbox.tileLayer('andria.h41061in')
},
 {
    'streets': L.mapbox.tileLayer('andria.h41061in'),

     'com_geojson': L.geoJson(comData,  {
      style: getStyle,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(mapdataviz),
    'bounds': L.mapbox.tileLayer('andria.cal_conf')
}).addTo(mapdataviz);



  var popup = new L.Popup({ autoPan: false });

  // comData comes from the 'us-states.js' script included above
  var comLayer = L.geoJson(comData,  {
      style: getStyle,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  })

  function getStyle(feature) {
      return {
          weight: 0.7,
          opacity: 0.5,
          color: 'white',
          fillOpacity: 0.8,
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.IEF1_2008)
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that transparency is not good for your purposes but this MapBox tutorial demonstrates how to put the geoJson layer behind the street map layer.

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/neighborhood-mapping-with-dynamic-vector-data-layers/

Is that helpful?